# How to Prevent SQL Injection about Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql-injection, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Such as this SQL:

```
select ':userid' as userid from (select [product] from my_dataset.products where userid = ':userid');
```

In order to write a safely SQL to query Google BigQuery's dataset, it seems here `where userid = ':userid'` is not safe.

Is there a way to rewrite it?

Comment: @Pentium10 Yes. But that seems didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Can you clarify how it didn't resolve the problem? If user input is fully escaped, they can't get out of your quoted string, so they cannot modify the structure of your query.